# Spring Boot - Nested Configuration Properties are not recognized

Tags: spring, spring-boot

As the title says, my custom properties are not registered when Application is starting. Would you mind taking a look?

My `custom.yml`:

```
bridge:
  url: xxx
  authentication:
    auth-url: xxx
    user: xxx
```

My `BridgeProperties.java`:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:custom.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(
        prefix = "bridge"
)

public class BridgeProperties {
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    protected ApiProperties apiProperties = new ApiProperties();
}
```

My `ApiProperties.java`:

```
  public class ApiProperties {
    protected String url;
    protected ApiProperties.Authentication authentication;
    // getter and setter

    public ApiProperties() {
    }

    public static class Authentication {
      protected String authUrl;
      protected String user;
      public Authentication() {}
      // getter and setter
    }
```

My Application's entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources(value = {
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.yml"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:custom.yml")
})

public class IntegrationService {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationService.class, args);
    }
}
```

When printing to the command line, I get null instead of the values I assigned to url, auth-url, and user in the `custom.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the Baeldung Site](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#6-alternative-yaml-files):

> It's also worth mentioning that YAML files do not support the @PropertySource annotation, so if we need to use this annotation, it would constrain us to using a properties file.

If you really need to import additional external file in yaml format, you have to implement your own `PropertySourceFactory` like in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource).

For me I do not see the advantage not using the default `application.yml` as you can define multiple sections managed by different `Properties` classes.

For example, if you just put your properties in the application.yml and if you compile with a recent JDK (>=jdk 14) you can even use the record for managing your properties in a very compact manner:

What you have to do is just to add the `EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BridgeProperties.class)
public class IntegrationService {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationService.class, args);
    }
}
```

and define a record for mapping your yaml properties:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bridge")
public final record BridgeProperties(String url, Authentication authentication) {
    public record Authentication(String authUrl, String user){
    }
}
```

Remember you can also define environment variable in profiles like `application-dev.yml` if you start your app with profile `dev` and another one e.g. for production `application-prd.yml` if your profile for production is named `prd`. You can still keep the common properties in the `application.yml`.

If you really want to go in the external file path, I suggest to switch to .properties as the `@PropertySource` supports it natively.